# Work done by air resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

How can air resistance do work on a freely falling body on earth.   then it's displacement is only due to gravity. I think Air resistance doesn't displace the body falling. So what is the meaning of work done by air resistance.

Answer (score 1):

The forces of air resistance are directed against the direction of the falling body, so air resistance performs a negative work, which is typically the case with friction forces.

We can also say that the falling body, powered by the gravity, performs a positive work on the air it displaces or, alternatively, the force of gravity performs a positive work on the air by pulling the body to the ground.

In general, due to the Newton's third law, any time A performs some positive work on B, B performs negative work of the same magnitude on A.

Answer (score 0):

It is displacing the object in the sense that without the resistance, your object would be moving faster and thus be at a different spot.

In the rest frame of a freely falling object (no air resistance) your object appears to be accelerated backwards. So the friction has effectively displaced the object.